# Strange screen at bootup Xubuntu 16

Tags: boot, nvidia, xubuntu

A saw a complain about Ubuntu 14, but the picture is no longer available, so I don't know if is the same problem of mine.

Photo: Xubuntu booting with style:

[image]

I just installed Xubuntu 16 and I'm very happy with the result so far, but when it boots, the first screen is an abstract art picture. I'm thinking in donate or sell this old machine and, well, should I worry with this or can I say it's "normal" and everything will be ok?

The machine: Pentium 4 with 3GB RAM, 128MB of nVidia Geforce Fx 5200. I tried two different monitors and both got the same screen.

EDIT: I tested sleep function (suspend) by keyboard and got and error when trying yo wake up: [1730.700423] ata3.-1: revalidation failed (errno=-19). It hangs and there is strange colored pixels behind this text, some vertical bars flicking.

Comment: it should the nvidia driver

Answer (score 1):

I did fix my problems with this AGP video card by changing a setting in bios: plug & play OS ENABLED. With this setting enabled (might have a different name in other CPU) the BIOS will allow the OS to configure the devices on the fly. It means now Xubuntu can configure correctly the video card when booting, otherwise, it's like "he think" been configured, but no!

This problem didn't happens when installing Windows XP, all other as Windows 7, 8, 10, Linux distributions will have problems and maybe not even start.